# Execute Command after VM Booted

Tags: bash, virtualbox

I've gotten sick of how many steps it takes me to get started in the morning.  Yes it only takes me a few minutes to start up my whole environment, but I'd really rather just run a single command on boot-up and be ready to go immediately.

I'm writing an app on Rails connected to SqlServer.  To develop for it I have a local version of the DB I use on a VM.  My manual process goes like this:

```
Run VirtualBox.
Start the VM.
     When the VM is done booting:
          Open terminal
          Run `rails s`
          When rails is done starting:
                 open browser
                 navigate to localhost:3000 and start developing
Run Sublime
```

I'd love to do this in one script:

```
VirtualBox Windows7 &
sublime &
google-chrome &
```

But I can't figure out how to run this command *only* once the VM is done booting:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=git/my_project --tab -e 'rails s' --tab -e 'git status'
```

Also, it'd be nice (but not necessary) to have chrome start *after* rails s has succeeded.

Is this even possible?

I'm not opposed to polling, but it feels like this is something VirtualBox should be able to do a bit more naturally.

**EDIT**

From Comment:

I'm using Host-Only network with two Bridged Interfaces (one for wireless and one for wired) available. (It allows me to use the VM whether or not I'm connected to a network, and lets me freely switch between wired and wireless without noticing the difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do:

1. In the VM, create a script which will find the default gateway, & keep pinging to it. & add it to user's startup. (needs parsing of `ipconfig /all` which can be done with vbscript/python.)
2. In host, look at the network interface between host & VM. Find the default gateway on host (parse `route -n` output in bash script). Since both use same physical interface, the gateway would be same (assuming NAT & ONE physical interface). Use tcpdump, to wait for the ping packets to the gateway.

"Default gateway" was chosen because that was something host & VM can find out independent of each other. Other alternative was to hard-code host's address.

After the host tcpdump on host exits, it means that the VM is alive & booted upto windows desktop.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's a good point. I'm using Host-Only network with two Bridged Physical Interfaces available. (It allows me to use the VM whether or now I'm connected to a network, and lets me freely switch between wired and wireless without noticing the difference).  I will add this to the question. I'm sorry I didn't give that information before.

Comment: Also, I might be loading the VM from a snapshot rather than fresh.  The user's startup would not get run in that case.

Comment: 1. Maybe then ping a fixed address (which might not get answered) & capture the ping packets.

Comment: If ping was already running while taking snapshot, will it run after starting from snapshot? I have `ping -t IP_ADDRESS` in my script. I am trying to say, that putting the script in startup is one time work & start it then itself.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this line of inquiry before, and I think Devil's Pie is the closest you can get to setting that up:

http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie

Comment: Except that the window is created long before the VM is done booting.

Answer (score 0):

You could try starting with this (VBoxManager startvm):

[How to automatically start and shut down VirtualBox machines?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28611/how-to-automatically-start-and-shut-down-virtualbox-machines)

and then look at some working scripts to add to your init.d and/or rc.local once your VM is up to finish the rest of the job in order:

[Get To Know Linux: The /etc/init.d Directory](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I already know how to start and stop the machine from the command line, and the machine is a windows machine....

Answer (score 0):

I needed to orchestrate something similar.  I'm using a Windows VM (guest) as a proxy (it runs a Windows-only corporate VPN client) for my Linux laptop (host).  The approach is to **fully automate the guest** and wait until it's ready:

1. The host must have no funky routes (yet)
2. The VM starts and runs a powershell script (via Windows Task Scheduler, run-on-startup) that connects the VPN client and sets up ICS (Internet Connection Sharing, basically routing).
3. The host now adds funky routes that send some traffic via the VM's host-only interface.  If it added these routes too soon, step 2 would not work.
4. The VM also runs [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) (http proxy) and its port is NAT port forwarded from the host, so **localhost:3128** actually goes to the guest.  So a curl using this proxy goes to the corporate network and indicates whether the guest is fully up and connected.

(Squid is also useful as a backup to this complicated but very convenient mechanism, I can still ssh via corkscrew, etc)

So, I run this script on the host (simplified version shown):

```
#!/bin/bash
VM=vm  #Name of the Virtual Machine
SCRIPT_DIR=/some/dir
PROXY_ADDRESS=localhost:3128 
REMOTE_CURL_HOST=any.corporate.hostname

function waitloop() {
    echo -n "Waiting to hear from $REMOTE_CURL_HOST "
    while ! curl -s -m 5 --proxy $PROXY_ADDRESS $REMOTE_CURL_HOST > /dev/null ; do
        echo -n .
        sleep 10
    done
    echo "!"
}

# a separate script that takes down my routes, you may not need this.
bash $SCRIPT_DIR/network-config-vboxnet0.sh down

# error is OK if it's already running
vboxmanage startvm $VM

waitloop && bash $SCRIPT_DIR/network-config-vboxnet0.sh up && echo "Completed"
```

Essentially, the script waits until curl works through the VM.